# What will be the Worst case Time complexity for this?

Tags: algorithm

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i* = 2)
for(int j = 1 ; j < i ; j* = 2)
```

Can anyone explain me this?
I think it is `log(n)*log(i)` .Is that correct?

Comment: I think nlog(i); as we see it run from 1 to n times so it will be n and for i it depends on n , not sure but may be it will log(i); so it will be n*log(i); let me know what you say.

Comment: @Mudasar although it runs from 1 to n, but always get increased by a factor of 2, so i think it cant be n*log(i).

Comment: i think the worst complexity would be log(n)*log(n).

Comment: You need to eliminate `i` from the output. Relate `i` to `n` and use the relation.

Comment: 'i' is not a parameter, it is a loop control variable.

Comment: Is this C code? if so, `i* = 2` is a syntax error. Do you mean `i *= 2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
   for (j = 1; j < i; j *= 2)
      ...stuff...
```

"stuff" will be run 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + log(n)-1 times.  Since the sum of integers 1 to N is N * (N + 1) / 2, worse case run time is O(log(n) ^ 2).

Comment: I agree with the reasoning.  I also checked it empirically and it holds.